# Can I pass a char where an integer is expected in printf?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

Is the following code correct?

```
char mychar = 200;
printf("%x", mychar);
```

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ `%x` expects an integer (4 bytes with my compiler) and I only pass 1 byte here. Since `printf` makes use of varargs, my fear is that this only works because of byte alignment on the stack (i.e. a char always uses 4 bytes when pushed on the stack).

I think it would be better to write:

```
char mychar = 200;
printf("%x", static_cast<int>(mychar));
```

Do you think the first code is safe anyway? If not, do you think I could get a different output if I switch to a bigendian architecture?

Comment: Personally, I would just play it safe and write `(int)mychar`; in the worst case I wasted five characters, in the best case I avoided UB. Also, as always with dusty corners of the language, I prefer to be extra clear/safe also to avoid to puzzle future readers of my code.

Comment: Interessting question, does printf implitely cast? With a static_cast your always on the safe side

Comment: @Paranaix: it's not `printf` per se, but variable arguments that promotes some types (e.g. `float` is always promoted to `double`).

Comment: @Matteo Italia Well, i rather thought about conversion in the function itself (and therefore implementation depending) than about conversion at the call itself

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your example, the argument is actually of type `int`. `mychar` is promoted to `int` due to the *default argument promotions*.

> (C99, 6.5.2.2p6) "If the expression that denotes the   called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. **These are called the default argument promotions.**"

and (emphasis mine):

> (C99, 6.5.2.2p7) "**If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype,** the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. **The default argument
>   promotions are performed on trailing arguments**."

Note that technically the `x` conversion specifier requires an `unsigned int` argument but `int` and `unsigned int` types are guaranteed to have the same representation.

Comment: @Naveen: Yes, C++11 5.2.2/7 says more or less the same thing.

Comment: @Naveen: Yes, pretty much. C++ from time to time had different types (e.g. `bool`) which had their own promotion rules, but otherwise it's the same.

Comment: I see. However we are using C++ here. Can you confirm the C++ standard says the same?

Comment: @happy_emi as Mike said, C++ has basically the same rule in C++11, 5.2.2p7 and also calls them the default argument promotions.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but when `sizeof(int)==1` and `char` is `unsigned` per default, then a `char` is not promoted to `int` but `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 3):

This only works for you because your platform is able to interpret an `int` (to which your `char` is promoted) as an `unsigned`, this is what `%x` expects. To be sure that this always works you should use and appropriate format specifier, namely `%d`.

Since it seems that you want to use `char` as numerical quantity it would be better to use the two alternative types `signed char` or `unsigned char` to make your intention clear. `char` can be a signed or unsigned type on function of your platform. The correct specifier for `unsigned char` would then be `%hhx`.

Comment: Doesn't using `%d` only work reliably under the very assumption that `char` is signed?

Comment: C says `int` and `unsigned int` have same size and same alignment requirement in C99, 6.2.5p6.

Comment: @larsmans, it could only fail on a hypothetical architecture where `char` is unsigned *and* have the same width as `unsigned int`. On all other architectures `char` promotes to `int` and not to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @ouah, yes, but `unsigned int` could have padding bits and trap representations. Though this is unlikely, and it is even more unlikely to encounter such a trap representation when promoting from a `char` :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [printf("%hhx", mychar)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). And please, don't use cplusplus.com as a reference. This question only proves its reputation of containing many errors and leaving out a lot of information.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using C++, then you might want to use streams instead.

You will need to cast characters to integers, otherwise they will be printed as glyphs. Also, signed characters will be sign extended during the cast, so it's better to use unsigned char. For example a char holding 0xFF will print as 0xFFFFFFFF unless casted to unsigned char first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(void){

    char c = 0xFF;
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0');
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off topic - there are good reasons to keep using stdio in C++.